# How can a C# Method return only after Event has been fired?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, synchronization

I have a DLL `SomeLib.dll`, that contains a `DeleteHandler` object:

```
public class DeleteHandler
{
    private _handlerToServerObj;

    public DeleteHandler()
    {
        _handlerToServerObj = new HandlerToServerObj(/* ... */);
        _handlerToServerObj.OnDelete += new OnDeleteEventHandler(OnDeleteEH);
    }

    public void Delete(string id)
    {
        _handlerToServerObj.Delete(id);
    }

    private void OnDeleteEH(string id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

How it works:

- `_handlerToServerObj.Delete(id)` is sending a message to the server and the call immediatly returns;
- when the server has successfully deleted the item, it will fire the `OnDelete` event.

This library is normally used by a `WinForms` application.

Normally, I would like for the `Delete()` method to return **only** after the server has indeed deleted the item (i.e., the `OnDelete` event is fired and, therefore, the `OnDeleteEH` is executed).

I've tried using a `ManualResetEvent`, but with no success (i.e., the `OnDeleteEH` is never called):

```
private ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void Delete(string id)
{
    _waitHandler.Reset();
    _handlerToServerObj.Delete(id);
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
}

private void OnDeleteEH(string id)
{
    //
    _waitHandle.Set();
}
```

Or:

```
private ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void Delete(string id)
{
    _waitHandler.Reset();
    Thread thread = new Thread(PrivateDelete);
    thread.Start(id);
    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
}

private void PrivateDelete(string id)
{
    _handlerToServerObj.Delete(id);
}

private void OnDeleteEH(string id)
{
    //
    _waitHandle.Set();
}
```

Is this design valid? If yes, what are the mistakes that I'm making while implementing? If no, ca you please suggest corrections?

[Edit 1]

Corrected some mistakes with respect to the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're shadowing your wait handle in the method, which results in you waiting on a handle that is never being set.

Instead of declaring a new variable named `_waitHandle` within `Delete` you need to use the instance field.

Of course, you could simplify the code if you use an anonymous event handler, rather than another method:

```
public void Delete(string id)
{
    ManualResetEvent waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    _handlerToServerObj.OnDelete += () => waitHandle.Set();
    _handlerToServerObj.Delete(id);
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

If you use a closure here like this then you don't need the handle to be an instance field at all.

---

Having said all of that, if you're using this within the context of a desktop UI application you probably don't *want* to have a blocking method; you probably want to do work like this asynchronously, not synchronously.  If called in the UI thread you'll be blocking the UI thread, and creating a new worker thread just so that it can spend all of its time blocking on some asynchronous IO operation is just wasteful.  While there can be some contexts in which you really want to wait on this event, take the time to be sure it's correct for your specific situation.

Comment: +1 Note that this fixes immediate issue the question is about. Using synchronous waits (`Sleep`, `WaitOne`...) on UI thread will at least freeze UI or can cause deadlocks in cases when other thread need to post result to UI thread. Consider using new `async`/`await` instead if possible.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, was putting a note about that into an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `_handlerToServerObj.OnDelete += waitHandle.Set()` doesn't work because the compiler complains that it cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'OnDelete'. Moreover, I need the `OnDeleteEH` event handler to do some verifications. I did a mistake while writing the question (i.e., declaring the `_waitHandle` in the wrong place). Therefore, I've edited the question and now things seem to be in place. Of course, the **issue still remains**. Suggestions?

Comment: @Yeseanul The event handler not compiling was me just forgetting to add the lambda portion; that's edited in.  If the handler needs to do other things as well, just have it do other things; that's fine.

Comment: 1) Because I **have** to use .NET 2.0, I took your sample code and replaced `_handlerToServerObj.OnDelete += () => waitHandle.Set();` with `_handlerToServerObj.OnDelete += delegate(string id){ waitHandle.Set(); };`. Unfortunately, `waitHandle.Set()` is never called and the code remains hanging on `waitHandle.WaitOne()`. 2) With respect to the sample code from my question (not using an anonymous event handler), can you please explain **why** it's not working and **how** to improve it (again, the behavior is: `waitHandle.Set()` is never called and the code hangs on `waitHandle.WaitOne()`)?

Comment: @Yeseanul In that case the most likely option, without knowing anything about what actual object you're using, is that the object is trying to marshal to the UI thread for the event handler, which you're blocking with this code.  The solution is to not do that, and write your program asynchronously instead of synchronously.

Comment: Having in mind that the client (e.g., UI thread) will be using this library in the following way: step 1 - do some calculations, step 2 - call `Delete()`, step 3 - wait until you know for sure that the item was deleted (or not), step 4 - do some calculations (and steps 1-4 are in a `Tick` event handler), do you have some ideas with respect to passing from synchronous to asynchronous (or how to keep it synchronous and also working as expected)?

Comment: @Yeseanul Given that case one can be 100% confident that this *shouldn't* be done synchronously.  That would be blocking the UI thread until this operation completes; even if you could do that, you wouldn't want to.  You should be programming this asynchronously, meaning that your method should accept a callback and the caller should provide the callback method to be run after the deletion takes place.

Comment: I see. It makes sense. I'm not so familiar with this. Can you please point me to some resources where I can find more information and learn how to properly use it in this context?